# Standard symbol / notation for "x knows y", or the inverse

Tags: notation

What's the standard way to express "$x$ knows about $y$", or "$x$ has no knowledge of $y$" in cryptographic notation?

Example (PRNG predictor):

$\exists f : P(f(G(k)|_{0..n}) = G(k)|_{n+1}) \geq 0.5 + \epsilon$, for non negligable $\epsilon$, **where $f$ has no knowledge of $k$**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation is "", i.e., the empty string. $\;\;$ Since $k$ is not an input of $f$, $f$ has no knowledge of $k$.

Comment: So you're saying there's no such notation?

Comment: @Polynomial He's saying that in your example such a notation is not necessary, because it's implicit in the parameters of $f$. A function by definition only knows what it sees in its parameters.

Comment: But your example is problematic, since you did not restrict the cost of calculating $f$. If you make no such restriction, you need entropy exceeding the output size, i.e. a true RNG, and not a PRNG.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I was just using it as an example. If I were really writing that in a document, I'd put something like "where $f(x)$ runs in polynomial time or better".

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted a symbol for that, I suppose you could borrow a notation from probability theory and write $f \perp k$ for "$f$ is independent of $k$".  But that's definitely not standard usage, so you're going to have to define it explicitly.